# JSON format for geometry_msgs/PoseStamped

Tags: rosbridge, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to publish a JSON message type using PoseStamped through rosbridge, I tried searching online but there wasn't any information about it. So, how do I go about doing it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38850/json-format-for-geometry_msgs/posestamped/) by [RJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/2492/rj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The structure of geometry_msgs/PoseStamped is documented here: http://ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseStamped.html

A PoseStamped message in JSON would therefore look as follows:

```
{ 
    header: { 
        seq: <int>, 
        stamp:  {
            secs: <int>,
            nsecs: <int>
        },
        frame_id: <string>
    },
    pose: {
        position: {
            x: <float>,
            y: <float>,
            z: <float>
        },
        orientation: {
            x: <float>,
            y: <float>,
            z: <float>,
            w: <float>
        }
    }
}
```

The entire JSON message that you would send to rosbridge to publish the message would be:

```
{
    receiver: "/topic",
    type: "geometry_msgs/PoseStamped",
    msg: { ...as above... }
}
```

Cheers,
Jon

---

Originally posted by [Jon Mace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1507/jon-mace/) with karma: 431 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4